# Use/Expose Service call composition to multiple modules in the same project

Tags: java, lagom

In the [Service call composition](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/ServiceImplementation.html#Service-call-composition) there's I tested the logged example and it worked as expected

```
    public  ServerServiceCall logged(ServerServiceCall serviceCall) {
        return HeaderServiceCall.compose(requestHeader -> {
            System.out.println("Received " + requestHeader.method() + " " + requestHeader.uri());
            return serviceCall;
        });
    }
```

I changed the implementation to validate the access token in the request header and I find it useful to use the same implementation in multiple modules in my projects in stead of copy/paste. 
To do that I :

- created a module called `common-tools` in my project
- Created a service called AuthorizationService and its implemenatation
- created a CommunModule class and overrided `configure` method
- tried to override the `Descriptor descriptor()` method 
  but I couldn't  make it compile, it always fails to compile 
  this is the method :

```
    @Override
    default Descriptor descriptor() {
        Descriptor descriptor = named("security").withCalls(
                Service.call(this::logged)
        ).withAutoAcl(true);
        return descriptor;
    }
```

Console output :

```
no suitable method found for call(this::logged)
[ERROR] method com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.api.Service.call(akka.japi.function.Creator>) is not applicable
    [ERROR] (cannot infer type-variable(s) Request,Response
    [ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    [ERROR] method com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.api.Service.call(java.lang.reflect.Method) is not applicable
    [ERROR] (cannot infer type-variable(s) Request,Response
    [ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.lang.reflect.Method is not a functional interface))
    [ERROR] method com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.api.Service.call(com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.api.Descriptor.CallId,java.lang.Object) is not applicable
    [ERROR] (cannot infer type-variable(s) Request,Response
    [ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Answer (score 1):

The way `logged` is defined is as a wrapper for another service call. However, in the `Descriptor` definition above, it is not wrapping another call.

You would normally not add this type of wrapper method directly to a descriptor, but use it inside some other service call definition as shown in the [documentation on service call composition](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/ServiceImplementation.html#Service-call-composition).

```
public ServerServiceCall<String, String> sayHello() {
  return logged(
      name -> completedFuture("Hello " + name)
  );
}
```

This would then appear in the `Descriptor` without referencing the wrapper method:

```
@Override
default Descriptor descriptor() {
    return named("security").withCalls(
            call(this::sayHello)
    ).withAutoAcl(true);
}
```

There's an example of a shared module in the [Online Auction Java](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java) example project. The `security` sub-module, is used by several service implementations.

Have a look at how `ServerSecurity.authenticated` is [implemented](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java/blob/master/security/src/main/java/com/example/auction/security/ServerSecurity.java) and [used in a service call](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java/blob/08bb08168c7df7eeca34702975f0c6fc70881309/item-impl/src/main/java/com/example/auction/item/impl/ItemServiceImpl.java#L79-L88).